# 'No match was found ..' when installing a module with -MinimumVersion

Tags: powershell

I believe I might be misunderstanding the `-MinimumVersion` parameter of `Install-Module`

The help states

> Specifies the minimum version of a single module to install. The version installed must be greater than or equal to MinimumVersion. If there is a newer version of the module available, the newer version is installed.

However, with the following command

```
Install-Module -Name RunAsUser -MinimumVersion 2.3.1
```

I receive this error

```
PackageManagement\Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'RunAsUser'.
Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
```

If I instead run

```
Install-Module -Name RunAsUser -RequiredVersion 2.3.1
```

It will install version 2.3.1 successfully. If I run

```
Install-Module -Name RunAsUser
```

It will install the latest which is 2.4.0 Am I misusing the `-MinimumVersion` parameter?

Powershell version 5.1.19041.2364

Comment: That is curious - I don't see the same symptom. Have you tried upgrading the `PowerShellGet` module?

Comment: @mklement0 `Get-Module Powershellget` shows                         
`ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, 
`

Comment: @mklement0 -listavailable shows `Script     2.2.5     
Script     1.0.0.1`

Comment: `Install-Module -Name RunAsUser -MinimumVersion 2.3.1` works fine for me on Core and WinPwsh

Comment: You could try something like `Install-Module -Force PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser` to see if that makes a difference. It seem that it updates both the `PowerShellGet` and `PackageManagement` modules.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that's great for you, how does that help me? lol  https://imgur.com/a/qEEVX6L

Comment: @mklement0 https://imgur.com/a/ECAubZl

Comment: Try either starting a new session or using `-AllowClobber`, as the error message suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction, Michael! We all benefit greatly from your presence here. You are a god among men (and women)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to update PowershellGet with -Scope CurrentUser

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this
system:'Find-Package,Install-Package,Uninstall-Package'. This module 'PackageManagement' may override the existing
commands. If you still want to install this module 'PackageManagement', use -AllowClobber parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
```

Seemed like all these issues related to 1.0.0.1 so I simply went into `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules\PowerhsellGet`  and moved the folder `1.0.0.1` out of there. Now everything is working as expected.